# Adding custom field in General setting TAB in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, image-uploading

I want to add a custom field in General setting TAB in wordpress.
This are the present fields that wordpress has it by default.

1. Site Title
2. Tag line
3. Wordpress Address URL
   ...etc

I want to add a custom field like, I want to have an image upload field.

For that I had to edit
**`options-general.php`** ,
**`options.php`**,
**`general-template.php`**,
I had to insert an entry in **`wp-options`** table in my database

Now when I tested it with a simple **`input type as text`** it worked well.
But when I set the **`input type as file`** for my logo upload it doesn't work this is my code below.
**`options-general.php`**

```
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="logo"><?php _e('Logo') ?></label></th>
<td><input name="file" type="file"/></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I have placed my image field right under my blog description field, and the action of this form takes me to **`options.php`**.
this is my **`option.php`**

```
if ( is_multisite() && !is_super_admin() && 'update' != $action )
    wp_die(__('Cheatin&#8217; uh?'));
/* image upload function goes here */

if($_POST['submit']){

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("images/logo/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/logo/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
}
    /* image upload function ends here */
```

Above I have added the simple image upload script, some how it doesn't work, nor the file is uploaded to the directory.

Does core PHP code works in WP environment  Or I'm missing on something, Kindly suggest.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid PHP to me.  You have `}option.php` in a couple of places, and this `}images/logo/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))` looks weird too.  The SO syntax highlighter is showing code as strings and vice versa - you're missing a `"` somewhere.

Comment: @Hobo I have edited my code above kindly check.

Comment: What output are you getting?  Anything in your PHP logs?

Comment: @Hobo I'm not getting anything. When I click on save after I set the image in my upload field, it says "Settings Saved.". But doesn't upload the image nor the database field that I have set in wp-options table

Comment: Given you have an `echo` in each branch of your code, you should see some output if the code is running.  Which seems to imply it's not running.  `$_POST['submit']` definitely set?  You've uploaded the right file to the right place?  And there's nothing in the PHP logs?  Core PHP does work in the WP environment, to answer that part of your question.  Is `$_FILES` an array?  Maybe you should loop over it?

Comment: You can't modify the Question this way, my Answer doesn't make sense anymore. Open another one. Please, refer to [meta.se] if you have any questions regarding my rollback.

Answer (score 6):

### Stop the machines!

You're [`_doing_it_wrong()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L3032), although this function does not detect what you're doing :)
We don't touch core file, [we do plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). Please, restore your WP to a fresh state.

---

#### Answering to the Question title

> *Adding custom field in General setting TAB in wordpress*

Follows an example from [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59304/12615). The key function is [`add_settings_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field), right now it adds a full WP Editor, but it can be adjusted to show any kind of field. A [nice article](http://kovshenin.com/2012/the-wordpress-settings-api/) that explains the Settings API.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Custom General Setting
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_57647_register_settings' );

/* 
 * Register settings 
 */
function wpse_57647_register_settings() 
{
    register_setting( 
        'general', 
        'html_guidelines_message',
        'esc_html' // <--- Customize this if there are multiple fields
    );
    add_settings_section( 
        'site-guide', 
        'Publishing Guidelines', 
        '__return_false', 
        'general' 
    );
    add_settings_field( 
        'html_guidelines_message', 
        'Enter custom message', 
        'wpse_57647_print_text_editor', 
        'general', 
        'site-guide' 
    );
}    

/* 
 * Print settings field content 
 */
function wpse_57647_print_text_editor() 
{
    $the_guides = html_entity_decode( get_option( 'html_guidelines_message' ) );
    echo wp_editor( 
        $the_guides, 
        'sitepublishingguidelines', 
        array( 'textarea_name' => 'html_guidelines_message' ) 
    );
}
```

[image: resulting settings]

Comment: +1 for the good point, and good example.  But it doesn't explain why the original code isn't working

Comment: @Hobo Well, then the OP has to justify why he's hacking WP core. Otherwise it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @brasofilo I really like the way you have set the UPload / Insert in General setting TAB. But this is something extra as there is a editor and gets confusing on the part, suppose if add image and enter some text under it, will that display along with the Image ? I wanted something simple as a image field. Thanks yo I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mckenzi, answer updated. It is only a demonstration of what can be done, you'll have to dig on from here :)

Comment: @brasofilo I have updated my Code in the question kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add an option to a site, but it doesn’t really need to be on its own page. You can probably add it to one of the existing settings pages. Here’s how to add an option to the General Settings page.

In this case, I’m adding a ‘favorite color’ field, probably not the best example, so go ahead and change that.

```
$new_general_setting = new new_general_setting();

class new_general_setting {
    function new_general_setting( ) {
        add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'register_fields' ) );
    }
    function register_fields() {
        register_setting( 'general', 'favorite_color', 'esc_attr' );
        add_settings_field('fav_color', '<label for="favorite_color">'.__('Favorite Color?' , 'favorite_color' ).'</label>' , array(&$this, 'fields_html') , 'general' );
    }
    function fields_html() {
        $value = get_option( 'favorite_color', '' );
        echo '<input type="text" id="favorite_color" name="favorite_color" value="' . $value . '" />';
    }
}
```

The third argument of the register_setting() function is the name of the function that should be used to validate the input data, so customize that as needed.